# Static IP not updating (MacOS)

Tags: networking, ip

I am attempting to create a static IP address.

I have followed the steps outlined [here](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/windows-mac-assign-static-ip-address/), and the changes are reflected here:

[image]

However, my static IP is not reflected when checking on this site:

https://whatismyipaddress.com/

Also, I can't connect using to mongodb with my static IP.

Any ideas would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good job learning to set yourself a static IP address. This is useful for keeping the IP address of a device on your local network from changing. For instance, a Raspberry Pi that you want to be able to control remotely over your home network.

However, what you set was your internal IP address. Your external IP address is assigned by your Internet Service Provider. For example, if you have AT&T U-verse internet, all devices in your house that are connected via WiFi or Ethernet cable to the AT&T router will have different internal IP addresses, but will share the same external IP address.

https://www.whatismyip.com/internet-ip-vs-local-ip/

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer! I'm trying to set up a static IP address for the purposes of an IP whitelist. I'm trying to `ssh` into a remote server, and want an IP address to avoid having to update the whitelist every time my dynamic IP address. For that purpose, do I need to change my external or internal IP address?

Comment: You could re-post this to get more answers, but I'll give mine here. I assume you are connecting via ssh to a server that is external to your network, via the internet. In this case you need to ask your Internet Service Provider to assign you a static IP. Mine charges a little more per month for this service.